# using if statement in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement

i am trying to develop an app that scans the existing WiFi signal surrounded my deceive and if specific WiFi signal is existed, the program will do specific instructions as follows in the program bellow :

```
 for (ScanResult result: results) {  
            int strength1 = info.getRssi ();
            float  strength_in_pre11=2*(strength1+100);
            float  Distance1 =30*(1-(strength_in_pre11/100));
tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        if (result.SSID.equals("WiFi1")) {
      String text="We are connecting to "+SSID+" Distance:"+Distance1+" " ;
            tv.setText (text);
        }

        else {
            String otherwifi1="The existing network is:\n\n";
     otherwifi1+=result.SSID+":"+result.level+"\n\n";
        otherwifi1+=result.SSID+":"+result.level+":"+Distance1+"\n";
        tv.setText (otherwifi1);
        }

    }
```

well , the if statement is not satisfied even though the router name that i put in the if statement (WiFi1)  is existed , only else condition is satisfied ?!
anyone can help

thank you

Comment: I assume there is some white space in SSID variable so try this way, `result.SSID.trim().equalsIgnorecase("WiFi1")`

Comment: result.SSID.toString.equals("WiFi1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what's the value of result.SSID :

```
System.out.println(result.SSID.toString());

if (result.SSID.toString().equals("WiFi1")) {
      String text="We are connecting to "+SSID+" Distance:"+Distance1+" " ;
      tv.setText (text);
    }
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your answer Ashwin

Comment: @AshwinSAshok 
i changed as you suggested but still does not work 
it still only doing the else instructions, moreover if i deleted the if condition it works , seems like the problem with if statement itself

Comment: post me value of System.out.println("SSI VALUE : "+result.SSID.toString());

Comment: @AshwinSAshok 
sorry what do you mean by the System.out.println("SSI VALUE : "+result.SSID.toString()); .. 
and if you mean the out out of the system .. it still shown the output of else statement

Comment: after running the appliction check the logcat for the output.

Comment: 05-07 15:43:07.210: I/System.out(28541): rubelwifii
05-07 15:43:07.210: I/System.out(28541): SSI VALUE : rubelwifii
05-07 15:43:07.210: I/System.out(28541): Bodybuilding
05-07 15:43:07.210: I/System.out(28541): SSI VALUE : Bodybuilding

Comment: @AshwinSAshok
noted : i`m using rubelwifii in my if condition instead of WiFi1

Comment: Use rublewifii in the if condition for checking instead of wifi1.

Comment: @AshwinSAshok 
I am using it actually
 if (result.SSID.toString().equals("rubelwifii"))

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and put a log or syso to see what the ssid is ? and whether it has whitespaces or quotes around the actual name?

i current did something similar and i had to change my if to the following as the ssids i encountered had quotes

```
if (result.SSID.equals('"' + "WiFi1" + '"'))
```

Comment: thanks for your quick feedback 
i changed as you suggested but still does not work it still only doing the else instructions, moreover if i deleted the if condition it works , seems like the problem with if statement itsel